# Mysql update column from a table to another one if column value is similar to another comma separated column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with two tables.
Table1 looks like this:

```
uid | text              |reference  |
-------------------------------------
1   |                   | 1         |
2   |                   | 1,2       |
3   |                   | 2         |
4   |                   | 3         |
5   |                   | 1,3,2,4,5 |
6   |                   | 5         |
7   |                   | 4         |
```

Table2 looks like this

```
uid | text              |
-------------------------
1   | text1             |
2   | text2             |
3   | text3             |
4   | text4             |
5   | text5             |
6   | text6             |
7   | text7             |
```

I would like to update Table1 so it becomes:

```
uid | text                          | reference |
---------------------------------------------------
1   | text1                         | 1         |
2   | text2 text2                   | 1,2       |
3   | text2                         | 2         |
4   | text3                         | 3         |
5   | text1 text3 text2 text2 text5 | 1,3,2,4,5 |
6   | text5                         | 5         |
7   | text4                         | 4         |
```

I've found the following command and haven't been able to adapt it to my case

```
UPDATE table1 AS text
INNER JOIN table2 AS text 
    ON table1.reference = table2.reference
SET table1.text = table2.text
```

The text column in `table1` should be updated comparing `table1.reference` with `table2.uid`. If reference value is 1, then the text corresponding to `table2.uid #1` will be copied to `table1.text`. If reference is 1,2 then the text corresponding to `table2.uid #1 and #2` will both be copied.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem shows why storing comma-separated values in a single row is a bad practice. This kind of relationships are better modeled with an additional relationship table, that in your case would look like this:

```
TableRef
uid  |referenceUid |
--------------------
1    | 1           |
2    | 1           |
2    | 2           |
3    | 2           |
4    | 3           |
5    | 1           |
5    | 2           |
5    | 3           |
5    | 4           |
5    | 5           |
...  | ...         |
```

This way, you could do the update you need like this

```
update  Table1 t1, (
            select  t3.uid, group_concat(t2.text order by t2.text separator ' ') as text
            from    TableRef t3
            join    Table2 t2
            on      t3.referenceUid = t2.uid
            group by t3.uid
        ) t4
set     t1.text = t4.text
where   t1.uid = t4.uid
```

You can see this query in action [here](http://rextester.com/DBAV22071)